# Call async function in generator got "TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable"?

Tags: python, asynchronous

The following code got the error of `TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable`

```
async def f(i):
    return i*10, i*100

l2 = [1,2,3]
[x for x in ((i, await f(i)) for i in l2)]
```

However, it works if not using generator?

```
[x for x in [(i, await f(i)) for i in l2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introducing the `async` keyword in the generator expression makes it become an async generator.

If you are using a recent Ipython as the REPL, when used as a list comprehension, the expression in the inner list is fully resolved.. Ipython special "call async functions in a transparent way" do just that, and all the outer loop "sees" is simply a list.

In normal Python code, or on the "pure" REPL, the `async` keyword use is restricted to async function bodies, and you'd get a `SyntaxError: asynchronous comprehension outside of an asynchronous function` error with both snippets anyway.

So, getting back to your problem: introducing an `await` in the expression in  the inner generator, it becomes an asynchronous generator - the outer code will need the inner code to be run on each iteration. But all you need is to use `async for` to get its values in the outer comprehension:

```
[x async for x in [(i, await f(i)) for i in l2]]
```